# ¿Como obtener la edad de una persona en años, meses y dias en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date

Como obtener la edad de una persona tomando como referencia la fecha de nacimiento y la fecha de hoy.

La diferencia en ambas fechas quiero alojarla en 3 variables, una para los años, otra para los meses y otra para los días. Lo que necesito es que cuando el usuario inserte su fecha de nacimiento en un INPUT de tipo Date se muestre su edad en Años y Meses y Dias y tengo como restricción denegarle el acceso si es menor de edad!! Aqui en México la mayoria de edad es a los 18 años por lo que les pongo un ejemplo

Si un usuario introduce la fecha `2002/07/27` y la hora del sistema es `2020/07/27` entonces el permiso seria `TRUE` pero si el usuario cambia la fecha a 2002/07/29 entonces se tendria que cambiar el permiso a `FALSE` porque faltarían 2 días para su cumpleaños.

Les adjunto algo de código que he estado probando pero por alguna extraña razón al crear un new Date me trae todo el formato de hora y entonces se pasa por algunos dias y eso me cambia el valor para los meses, como que tiene un desfazamiento por 4 dias.

```
/*Validación Fecha de Nacimiento Mayoria de edad del usuario*/
$("#fechaNacimientoNyN").change(function(){
    var fechaUsuario = this.value.toString();//Obtengo el valor del input del usuario
    /*------------*/
    //El siguiente fragmento de codigo lo uso para igualar la fecha de nacimiento con la fecha de hoy del usuario
    var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;
    d=[year, month, day].join('-')
    /*------------*/
    var hoy = new Date(d);//fecha del sistema con el mismo formato que "fechaUsuario"
    var cumpleanos = new Date(fechaUsuario);
    //alert(cumpleanos+" "+hoy);
    //Calculamos años
    var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleanos.getFullYear();
    var m = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleanos.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < cumpleanos.getDate())) {
        edad--;
    }
    // calculamos los meses
    var meses=0;
    if(hoy.getMonth()>cumpleanos.getMonth()){
        meses=hoy.getMonth()-cumpleanos.getMonth();
    }else if(hoy.getMonth()<cumpleanos.getMonth()){
        meses=12-(cumpleanos.getMonth()-hoy.getMonth());
    }else if(hoy.getMonth()==cumpleanos.getMonth() && hoy.getDate()>cumpleanos.getDate() ){
        if(hoy.getMonth()-cumpleanos.getMonth()==0){
            meses=0;
        }else{
            meses=11;
        }
        
    }
    //Me faltan los dias

    if(edad>=18){
        console.log("ERES UN ADULTO");
    }else{
        console.log("TU EDAD ES DE:"+edad+" años "+meses+" meses"+dias+" dias");
        console.log("TE FALTAN"+edad+" años "+meses+" meses"+dias+" dias PARA SER ADULTO");
    }});
```

Comment: Revisaste la fecha y hora del equipo donde pruebas?? ya que si esta no posee la fecha y hora actual puede generar diferencias al realizar dicha prueba, realizo pruebas con tu código y me valida bien la fecha de nacimiento. debes corregir cuando limpias el campo que genera un error. pero mira la fecha de tu equipo donde pruebas.

Comment: Si la revise y si me sale igual a la que tengo en mi sistema, lo que hice con la primer funcion fue darle el formato de YYYY/MM/DD porque al tomarla asi de cajon me mostraba toda la hora y el dia de la semana y no podia hacer la comparación con la fecha del usuario.

Comment: a claro, y también pasa el tema de la diferencia horaria. Eso hay que tenerlo muy en cuenta

Comment: te aconsejo mirar la libreria moment.js, lo que te han dicho esta bien pero a mi me gusta usar esta, implica adaptar un poco las repuestas que te han dado

Answer (score 8):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea calcular la edad de una persona, basados en la fecha introducida en un elemento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input) de tipo [`date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input#attr-type) y la fecha actual del sistema que ejecuta la validación.

Si la edad de la persona es menor a 18 años (exactos) se debe devolver `false` en caso contrario se debe devolver `true`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

El problema plantea dos desafíos muy claros, el primero tiene que ver con la zona horaria local del sistema y el constructor de fecha del elemento `input` tipo `date`. El segundo, determinar si la persona tiene 18 años cumplidos o no.

**UTC y el elemento `input`**

Cuando obtenemos la fecha a través del valor introducido en un elemento de tipo `input`, debemos tomar en cuenta la construcción de la misma. La fecha devuelta por un elemento `input` de tipo `date`, es una cadena con el formato `YYYY-MM-DD` sin tiempo.

Cuando creamos un objeto de tipo [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) de Javascript, usando como parámetro el valor devuelto por nuestro elemento `input`, el mismo será creado usando como horas, minutos, segundos y milisegundos el valor 0 (cero), y se hará usando la hora UTC correspondiente a 00:00:00.000.

Ejemplo:

```js
$('#fecha').change(e => {
  let fechaStr = e.currentTarget.value;
  let fechaDate = new Date(fechaStr);
  $('#salidaStr').text(fechaStr);
  $('#salidaDate').text(fechaDate);
  $('#salidaNow').text(new Date());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="fecha">Introduzca una fecha</label>
<br>
<input type="date" id="fecha">
<br>
<h4>Cadena obtenida del input</h4>
<p id="salidaStr">
<br>
<h4>Valor Date</h4>
<p id="salidaDate">
<br>
<h4>Valor Date del sistema</h4>
<p id="salidaNow">
```

Como podemos observar, el valor devuelto por el constructor `Date` establece la hora UTC para el objeto `Date` creado, y dependiendo de la zona horaria en la que se ejecute este código, tendremos una representación de cadena con la fecha correspondiente al horario local. Si estamos en la hora de Europa Central correspondiente al horario de verano, obtendremos el valor con GMT+0200, por ejemplo: *Wed Jul 29 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)*. Pero si estamos en el horario de la Ciudad de México, tendremos el valor con GMT-0500, por ejemplo: *Tue Jul 28 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central)*, pero con un día menos. Sin embargo, pese a que esa es la salida, el valor almacenado por el Objeto `Date` se corresponderá con un valor UTC (zona horaria GMT 0).

Si deseamos obtener el valor del día correspondiente a dicha fecha usando [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDate) nos devolverá el día según la hora local, y para toda fecha con zona horaria negativa nos devolverá un valor menor al declarado en nuestro elemento `input`.

**¿Y cómo obtengo el valor real?**

Usaremos los métodos `getUTC*` para asegurarnos que estamos obteniendo efectivamente el valor correcto tanto para la fecha introducida en el elemento `input` como para la fecha local del sistema.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let fechaHoy = new Date('2020-07-29');

console.log(fechaHoy.getUTCDate());
console.log(fechaHoy.getDate()); // será 1 día menos para zonas horarias negativas
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

De esta forma siempre obtendremos el valor en horario UTC de la fecha, tanto local como la que es declarada en el elemento `input`.

**Ser mayor de edad es mucho más que un simple número**

Una vez que hemos resuelto el problema de obtener la fecha correcta, vamos a resolver el problema de determinar si la persona tiene la mayoría de edad. En algunos países la mayoría de edad es a los 18 años. Por lo tanto vamos a tener una variable que indique este valor.

Para que una persona se considere mayor de edad debe tener los 18 años cumplidos, y esto lo calculamos observando el año de nacimiento, mes y día y comparándolo con el año, mes y día actual.

Si yo nací en 1976, y estamos en 2020, es evidente que tengo más de 18 años. Una simple resta nos dice que 2020 - 1976 es igual a 44.

En cambio si yo nací en 2010 y estamos en 2020, también es evidente que soy menor de edad, ya que 2020 - 2010 es igual a 10 años.

El problema se presenta en los nacidos hace 18 años desde la fecha del sistema. Por ejemplo, estando en 2020 y habiendo nacido en 2002, puedo tener 18 años cumplidos o no. Dependerá del mes actual y del mes de mi nacimiento.

Luego si el mes actual es igual al mes de mi nacimiento, sólo seré mayor de edad si mi día de nacimiento es menor o igual al día actual.

Esa es toda la lógica necesaria para determinar si (basados en la fecha del sistema y la fecha de nacimiento introducida) una persona es mayor de edad o no.

Podríamos escribir la siguiente función:

```js
const edadLegal = 18;
const esMayor = fechaNac => {
  if(!fechaNac || isNaN(new Date(fechaNac))) return;
  const hoy = new Date();
  const dateNac = new Date(fechaNac);
  if(hoy - dateNac < 0) return;
  const years = hoy.getUTCFullYear() - dateNac.getUTCFullYear();
  if(years < edadLegal) return false;
  if(years > edadLegal) return true;
  const meses = hoy.getUTCMonth() - dateNac.getUTCMonth();
  if(meses < 0) return false;
  if(meses > 0) return true;
  const dias = hoy.getUTCDate() - dateNac.getUTCDate();
  if(dias < 0) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Simple, y siguiendo la lógica que usamos en la vida real.

Veamos ahora un ejemplo de acuerdo a la pregunta planteada, que pretende mostrar la edad del usuario en un elemento tipo `input` indicando 3 valores: años, meses y días.

Será necesaria una función adicional que será ejecutada únicamente para mostrar estos valores.

Podría verse así:

```js
const edad = fechaNac => {
  if(!fechaNac || isNaN(new Date(fechaNac))) return;
  const hoy = new Date();
  const dateNac = new Date(fechaNac);
  if(hoy - dateNac < 0) return;
  let dias = hoy.getUTCDate() - dateNac.getUTCDate();
  let meses = hoy.getUTCMonth() - dateNac.getUTCMonth();
  let years = hoy.getUTCFullYear() - dateNac.getUTCFullYear();
  if(dias < 0) {
    meses--;
    dias = 30 + dias;
  }
  if(meses < 0) {
    years--;
    meses = 12 + meses;
  }
  return [years, meses, dias];
}
```

En esta función calculamos la diferencia en días, si la misma es negativa debemos restar 1 a la diferencia en meses, y si la diferencia en meses es negativa, debemos restar 1 a la diferencia en años.

Claro, en este caso particular no estoy tomando en cuenta el tema de los años bisiestos y hago uso de meses de 30 días. Es una primera aproximación de un problema más complejo que se puede resolver usando otro tipo de lógica.

Un código funcional podría ser el siguiente:

```js
const edadLegal = 18;
const esMayor = fechaNac => {
  if(!fechaNac || isNaN(new Date(fechaNac))) return;
  const hoy = new Date();
  const dateNac = new Date(fechaNac);
  if(hoy - dateNac < 0) return;
  const years = hoy.getUTCFullYear() - dateNac.getUTCFullYear();
  if(years < edadLegal) return false;
  if(years > edadLegal) return true;
  const meses = hoy.getUTCMonth() - dateNac.getUTCMonth();
  if(meses < 0) return false;
  if(meses > 0) return true;
  const dias = hoy.getUTCDate() - dateNac.getUTCDate();
  if(dias < 0) return false;
  return true;
}
const edad = fechaNac => {
  if(!fechaNac || isNaN(new Date(fechaNac))) return;
  const hoy = new Date();
  const dateNac = new Date(fechaNac);
  if(hoy - dateNac < 0) return;
  let dias = hoy.getUTCDate() - dateNac.getUTCDate();
  let meses = hoy.getUTCMonth() - dateNac.getUTCMonth();
  let years = hoy.getUTCFullYear() - dateNac.getUTCFullYear();
  if(dias < 0) {
    meses--;
    dias = 30 + dias;
  }
  if(meses < 0) {
    years--;
    meses = 12 + meses;
  }
  
  return [years, meses, dias];
}

$('#fechaNac').change(e => {
  let mayor = esMayor(e.currentTarget.value);
  let suEdad = edad(e.currentTarget.value);
  if(mayor) {
    $('#salida').text(`Usted es mayor de ${edadLegal} años`);
  } else {
    if(mayor === false) {
    $('#salida').text(`Usted es menor de ${edadLegal} años`);
    } else {
      $('#salida').text('Fecha no válida, verifique');
    }
  }
  if(suEdad) {
    $('#edad').val(`${suEdad[0]} año(s), ${suEdad[1]} mes(es) y ${suEdad[2]} día(s).`);
  } else {
    $('#edad').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="fechaNac">Introduzca su fecha de nacimiento:</label>
<br>
<input id="fechaNac" type="date">
<br>
<label for="edad">Su edad es: </label>
<input id="edad" type="text" size="30">
<br>
<p id="salida">
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Ten cuidado con el [problema del año 2038](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_a%C3%B1o_2038)

Comment: @JackNavaRow Pues faltan exactamente poco menos de 18 años para ese cataclismo, desde la publicación de esta respuesta. Espero que para esa fecha la respuesta sobrepase los 18 votos, ya que como se siga votando tan esporádicamente aquí en SOes, no hay mucha esperanza de que mi respuesta cumpla la mayoría de edad antes del cataclismo. XD

Comment: Hola, solo vengo a recordar que ahora faltan 15 años para el problema del año 2038 :P

Comment: Hola, solo vengo a recordar que ahora faltan 14 años para el problema del año 2038 :P

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener día del mes hay que usar `Date.getDate()`, tanto en *hoy* como en *cumpleanos*. Con eso puedes completar la edad actual y, con algunas restas, calcular el tiempo que falta para que cumpla 18 años.

Revisa los comentarios para ver qué y porqué se realiza cada operación:

```js
/*Validación Fecha de Nacimiento Mayoria de edad del usuario*/
function edad(fechaUsuario){
    //El siguiente fragmento de codigo lo uso para igualar la fecha de nacimiento con la fecha de hoy del usuario
    let d = new Date(),
      month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
      day = '' + d.getDate(),
      year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;
    d=[year, month, day].join('-')
    /*------------*/
    var hoy = new Date(d);//fecha del sistema con el mismo formato que "fechaUsuario"
    var cumpleanos = new Date(fechaUsuario);
    //alert(cumpleanos+" "+hoy);
    //Calculamos años
    var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleanos.getFullYear();
    var m = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleanos.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < cumpleanos.getDate())) {
        edad--;
    }
    // calculamos los meses
    var meses=0;
    if(hoy.getMonth()>cumpleanos.getMonth()){
        meses=hoy.getMonth()-cumpleanos.getMonth();
    }else if(hoy.getMonth()<cumpleanos.getMonth()){
        meses=12-(cumpleanos.getMonth()-hoy.getMonth());
    }else if(hoy.getMonth()==cumpleanos.getMonth() && hoy.getDate()>cumpleanos.getDate() ){
        if(hoy.getMonth()-cumpleanos.getMonth()==0){
            meses=0;
        }else{
            meses=11;
        }
        
    }
    // Obtener días: día actual - día de cumpleaños
    let dias  = hoy.getDate() - cumpleanos.getDate();
    if(dias < 0) {
        // Si días es negativo, día actual es mayor al de cumpleaños,
        // hay que restar 1 mes, si resulta menor que cero, poner en 11
        meses = (meses - 1 < 0) ? 11 : meses - 1;
        // Y obtener días faltantes
        dias = 30 + dias;
    }
    console.log(`Tu edad es de ${edad} años, ${meses} meses, ${dias} días`);

    if(edad>=18){
        console.log("Eres un adulto");
    }else{
        // Calcular faltante con base en edad actual
        // 18 menos años actuales
        let edadF = 18 - edad;
        // El mes solo puede ser 0 a 11, se debe restar (mes actual + 1)
        let mesesF = 12 - (meses + 1);
        // Si el mes es mayor que cero, se debe restar 1 año
        if(mesesF > 0) {
            edadF --;
        }
        let diasF = 30 - dias;
        console.log(`Te faltan ${edadF} años, ${mesesF} meses, ${diasF} días para ser adulto`);
    }
}
edad('2003-10-12');
edad('2002-8-1');
edad('2005-7-26');
```

Comment: Esto tiene muchos problemas, las fechas creadas así varían de acuerdo a la zona horaria. Además son demasiadas comprobaciones cuando en realidad se tienen sólo 3 casos por analizar: tiene más de 18 años, tiene exactamente 18 años o tiene menos de 18 años. Hoy ya es tarde en mi zona horaria, pero mañana con tiempo publicaré una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, en la pregunta se quiere mostrar edad actual y, en caso de ser menor de 18 años, tiempo que falta para "ser adulto", ambos casos en años, meses y días. El problema de OP era con el cálculo de días, que fe en lo que me enfoqué. Por otra parte, tanto fecha actual como cumpleaños se están manejando en el navegador, con la misma zona horaria. Estaré atento a tu propuesta, porque sé que hay muchas cosas que se pueden mejorar.