# aprobar formulario si el usuario es +18

Tags: reactjs, date

estoy usando datePiker de material-ui para la entrada de una fecha, dicha fecha se refiere a su nacimiento, el componente picker me permite ingresar una cierta fecha permitida pero no se como hacerlo, me ayudan

```
<DatePicker
   label="Basic example"
   name="nacimiento"
   value={usuario.nacimiento}
   onChange={handlePicker}
   className={classes.inputs}
   disableFuture
   openTo="year"
   format="dd/MM/yyyy"
   views={["year", "month", "date"]}
   minDate={new Date()} //aqui iria la logica para comprobar que sea mayor de 18 años
 />
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como obtener la edad de una persona en años, meses y dias en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376624/como-obtener-la-edad-de-una-persona-en-a%c3%b1os-meses-y-dias-en-javascript)

Comment: no response a mi pregunta, y las personas que votaron negativo me gustaría que justifiquen su votación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuese tú, usaría [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) para este propósito:

```
moment().subtract(18, 'years').toDate()
```

además, si es una fecha de nacimiento, deberías fijar la fecha máxima, no la mínima. Quedaría algo como:

```
<DatePicker
   label="Basic example"
   name="nacimiento"
   value={usuario.nacimiento}
   onChange={handlePicker}
   className={classes.inputs}
   disableFuture
   openTo="year"
   format="dd/MM/yyyy"
   views={["year", "month", "date"]}
   maxDate={moment().subtract(18, 'years').toDate()}
 />
```

Comment: prove usando moment.js, al verificar los datos antes de enviarlos al backend hice esto, `if(moment().diff(usuario.nacimiento, 'years') < 18) return setState({...state, nacimiento: true, errorTextNacimiento: 'Debes ser mayor de edad.'})` notas algo de diferencia en tu respuesta?

Comment: ok, me acabo de dar cuenta que con la respuesta que me facilitaste, no hace falta advertirle al usuario que sebe ser mayor, con tu código me ahorro varias acciones, muchísimas gracias.!

Comment: Es distinto, porque lo que te propongo es que el usuario ni siquiera pueda ingresar una fecha que esté dentro de los 18 años. Claramente eso debería validarse de igual maneja en el backend, pero eso ya es otra historia.