# date format with moment vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

espero puedan ayudarme, necesito mostrar este formato "2021-01-02" (YYY-MM-DD). Pero solo me muestra 1 digito en el mes y dia.

```
var moment = require('moment');

getNow: function() {
          const today = new Date();
          const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
          const date2 = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+(today.getDate()-1);
          const dateTime = date;
          const dateTime2 = date2;
          this.hoy = dateTime;
          this.ayer = dateTime2;
```

Y este es mi blade:

```
hoy @{{hoy}} - ayer @{{ayer}}
```

pero me muestra esto:

> hoy 2021-1-2 - ayer 2021-1-1

pero necesito que el formato sea "2021-01-02" porque necesito 2 digitos para comparar meses y dias

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo usando el operador [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart) del Objeto [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String) de Javascript.

De esta forma puedes añadir tantos ceros o caracteres que desees a una cadena (delante de ella) hasta completar el tamaño deseado.

```js
let cadena = "2";
cadena.padStart(2, "0"); // -> "02"
cadena.padStart(2, "+"); // -> "+2"
cadena.padStart(5, "0"); // -> "00002"
cadena.padStart(3, " "); // -> "  2"
cadena.padStart(6, "?"); // -> "?????2"
```

Para el caso de tu pregunta, podrías usar el método `padStart()` tanto al momento de obtener el mes (devuelve un entero entre 0 y 11) o el día (devuelve un entero entre 1 y 31 (o menos según el mes y año)). Eso hace que los valores de los primeros 9 meses o días sólo tengan 1 dígito, y necesitamos que tengan 2 dígitos, siendo el dígito "0" el que debemos añadir cuando esto sucede. Por lo tanto podemos escribir:

```
(today.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0")
// ...
today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0")
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
const mostrar = function() {
  const today = new Date();
  const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0")+'-'+today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const date2 = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0")+'-'+(today.getDate()-1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date2);
}

mostrar();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Si por alguna razón, el cliente no soporta el método `padStart()`, puedes usar tu propia implementación con un [operador condicional ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Operador_condicional_ternario): `condicion ? valor true : valor false`, implementado dentro de una [expresión literal de cadena](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings), que acepta una expresón de Javascript dentro de la plantilla, de la siguiente forma:

```
  `${expresion} resto de la cadena`
```

Por ejemplo, podrías hacer lo siguiente en tu caso:

```js
const date = `${today.getFullYear()}-${today.getMonth()+1 < 10 ? "0".concat(today.getMonth()+1) : today.getMonth() + 1 }-${today.getDate() < 10 ? "0".concat(today.getDate()) : today.getDate()};
```

Tal vez este código es más enredado, pero hace lo que deseamos, ya que devolverá una cadena con un caracter 0 delante en caso que el mes o el día sean menor que 10.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const mostrar = function() {
  const today = new Date(2021,0,2);
  const date = `${today.getFullYear()}-${today.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0".concat(today.getMonth() + 1) : today.getMonth() + 1 }-${today.getDate() < 10 ? "0".concat(today.getDate()) : today.getDate()}`;
  const date2 = `${today.getFullYear()}-${today.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0".concat(today.getMonth() + 1) : today.getMonth() + 1}-${today.getDate() - 1 < 10 ? "0".concat(today.getDate() - 1) : today.getDate() - 1}`
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date2);
}

mostrar();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Un problema en el formato actual que tienes en tu pregunta está en los casos en que la fecha actual sea el primer día del mes. En esos casos debes usar una lógica más compleja para que al restar el valor del día no produzca resultados extraños:

```js
const mostrar = function() {
  const today = new Date(2021, 0, 1);
  const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0")+'-'+today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const date2 = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0")+'-'+(today.getDate()-1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date2);
}

mostrar();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar, la fecha restada es: `2021-01-00`, lo cual es una fecha inválida desde cualquier punto de vista.

Puedes estudiar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376624/como-obtener-la-edad-de-una-persona-en-a%c3%b1os-meses-y-dias-en-javascript/377162#377162) donde uso parte de la lógica necesaria para hacer el cálculo correcto de la fecha en estos casos particulares. Sin embargo, podemos aprovechar las capacidades del constructor del objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) de Javascript para hacer que el cálculo lo haga por nosotros, para ello basta con construir la fecha de ayer usando:

```
const today = new Date(); // <- fecha de hoy
const yesterday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 1); // <- fecha de ayer sin errores aunque hoy sea primer dia del mes
```

De esta forma Javascript manejará sin problemas la construcción de la fecha de ayer (`getDate() - 1`) basado en la fecha que le pasamos al constructor.

Por ejemplo, en este caso se pasa la fecha del primer día del año y el Objeto `Date` muestra correctamente que el día anterior es precisamente el último día del año anterior:

```js
const mostrar = function() {
  const today = new Date(2021, 0, 1);
  const yesterday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 1);
  const date = `${today.getFullYear()}-${today.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0".concat(today.getMonth() + 1) : today.getMonth() + 1 }-${today.getDate() < 10 ? "0".concat(today.getDate()) : today.getDate()}`;
  const date2 = `${yesterday.getFullYear()}-${yesterday.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0".concat(yesterday.getMonth() + 1) : yesterday.getMonth() + 1 }-${yesterday.getDate() < 10 ? "0".concat(yesterday.getDate()) : yesterday.getDate()}`;
  console.log(date);
  console.log(date2);
}

mostrar();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.