# Enseñar campos de un formulario solo si se cumple que la persona tengo 18 o más años

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, formularios, laravel-8

estoy programando con Laravel, y me han pedido que a través de un formulario que rellena un cliente se le abran más campos si este es menor de 18 años. Los campos que quiero que se ejecuten cuando fechana(Fecha de Nacimiento) y la diferencia con la fecha actual sea menor a 18 son: nombrecompletome, direccionme, localidadme, provinciame, paisme, emailme, telefonome, vinculacionconmenor.

Me han pedido que lo haga por JavaScript(la funcion para que se abran los demás campos), pero también podría valer con PHP. de JavaScript solo encontré funciones las cuales no fui capaz de implementar(no controlo dicho lenguaje) y con php intente esto:

```
$fecha = time() - strtotime($cliente->fechana); 
$edad = floor($fecha / 31556926); //
```

(fecha se divide por la cantidad de segundos de un año natural) y también esto:

```
$fecha_nacimiento = new DateTime($cliente->fechana); 
$hoy = new DateTime(); 
$edad = $hoy->diff($fecha_nacimiento);
```

Seguido de una condición y si la fecha era menor a 18 que se mostrase lo demás. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="dni">DNI<br></label>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="dni" value="{{ old('dni', $cliente->dni)}}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="nombre"></label>
        <br>Nombre del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre', $cliente->nombre)}}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="apellidos"></label>
        <br>Apellidos del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="apellidos" value="{{ old('apellidos', $cliente->apellidos) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="fechana"></label>
        <br>Fecha de Nacimiento<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="date" name="fechana" value="{{ old('fechana', $cliente->fechana)}}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Url para el cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="url" value="{{ old('url', $cliente->url) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Codigo Postal del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="codigopostal" value="{{ old('codigopostal', $cliente->codigopostal) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Dirreción del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="direccion" value="{{ old('direccion', $cliente->direccion) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Localidad del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="localidad" value="{{ old('localidad', $cliente->localidad) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Provincia del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="provincia" value="{{ old('provincia', $cliente->provincia) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Pais del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="pais" value="{{ old('pais', $cliente->pais) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Email<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $cliente->email) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Telefono del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="telefono" value="{{ old('telefono', $cliente->telefono) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Nombre completo del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="nombrecompletome" value="{{ old('nombrecompletome', $cliente->nombrecompletome) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Direccion del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="direccionme" value="{{ old('direccionme', $cliente->direccionme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Localidad del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="localidadme" value="{{ old('localidadme', $cliente->localidadme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Provincia del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="provinciame" value="{{ old('provinciame', $cliente->provinciame) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>País del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="paisme" value="{{ old('paisme', $cliente->paisme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Email del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="emailme" value="{{ old('emailme', $cliente->emailme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Telefono del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="telefonome" value="{{ old('telefonome', $cliente->telefonome) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Vinculación del tutol con el menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="vinculacionconmenor" value="{{ old('vinculacionconmenor', $cliente->vinculacionconmenor) }}">
}

</div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">{{$btnText}}</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link btn-block btn-danger btn-lg" href="{{ route('cliente.index')}}">Cancelar</a>
```

Comment: Interesante... Qué has intentado? Nos puedes mostrar el javascript?

Comment: Lo siento por no especificar, de JavaScript solo encontré funciones las cuales no fui capaz de implementar(no controlo dicho lenguaje) y con php intente esto: 
$fecha = time() - strtotime($cliente->fechana);

$edad = floor($fecha / 31556926); 
(fecha se divide por la cantidad de segundos de un año natural)
y también esto:
$fecha_nacimiento = new DateTime($cliente->fechana);
$hoy = new DateTime();
$edad = $hoy->diff($fecha_nacimiento);
Seguido de una condición y si la fecha era menor a 18 que se mostrase lo demás. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hecho, graciaas

Comment: El tema de hacerlo con PHP, es que se ejecuta en el servidor, por lo que no va a ser reactivo a lo que haga el usuario en el formulario. Entonces si el usuario selecciona una fecha de nacimiento, va a tener que enviar el formulario al servidor para que haga los cálculos y devuelva otra vez el formulario con los correspondientes inputs

Comment: Ya que estás usando laravel, podrías probar [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/) si no quieres meterte con js. Pero sería una exageración instalarlo para sólo esa funcionalidad. Pero agregaste la etiqueta javascript y lo mencionas en la pregunta, por lo que tendrías que decidir cómo lo vas a hacer y avanzar en consecuencia

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Como obtener la edad de una persona en años, meses y dias en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376624/como-obtener-la-edad-de-una-persona-en-a%c3%b1os-meses-y-dias-en-javascript/377162#377162)

Comment: Buenas, si no he puesto nada de JavaScript es porque no conozco el lenguaje muy bien, voy aprendiendo a través de tutoriales y apuntes que me proporcionan conocidos, he preguntado porque me gustaría hacer el formulario que tengo pero el JavaScript y poder implementar la condición si es menor de edad pero no me consigo hacerlo. Con Laravel al menos he conseguido hacer el formulario pero no soy capaz de hacer que si no es menor de 18 no le salgan esos campos. Perdón por las molestias y muchas graciaas.