# Validar la edad mediante mi campo Javascript o Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $(function() {
 
  var edad = $('#Field2').val();
  
  let r1='mayor de edad';
  let r2='menor de edad';
  let r3='edad no valida';

  if (edad =='0') {
     
    
    document.getElementById("Field3").value = r3
   
    
  }else if (edad<='17'){
  
   document.getElementById("Field3").value = r2
 
  }else{
  
    document.getElementById("Field3").value = r1
  
  }   
});
```

Hola, quiero calcular si es mayor de edad una persona mediante un input obtener el valor e imprimirlo en otro campo en js tengo esto pero no me esta funcionando (me gustaría que si es igual a 0 y que no agarre números negativos)

Comment: Relacionado: [Cómo obtener la edad en años, meses y dias usando Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376624/como-obtener-la-edad-de-una-persona-en-a%c3%b1os-meses-y-dias-en-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: El problema es que estás comparando cadenas y no números. La solución rápida es convertir el valor a numérico para hacer comparaciones. Si quieres aprender por qué, sigue leyendo después del ejemplo.

En el ejemplo a continuación, hago la conversión a número al obtener el valor del input y luego comparo entre números.

```js
function validarEdad() {
  var edad = $('#Edad').val();
  edad = parseInt(edad);
 
  let r1='mayor de edad';
  let r2='menor de edad';
  let r3='edad no valida';
  
  var elemEstado = document.getElementById("EstadoEdad");

  if (edad <= 0) {
    elemEstado.innerHTML = r3
  } else if (edad <= 17) {
    elemEstado.innerHTML = r2
  } else {
    elemEstado.innerHTML = r1
  }   
}


$(function() {
  $("#Edad").on("input", function() {
     validarEdad(); 
  });
  validarEdad();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Edad" value="15" />
<span id="EstadoEdad">&nbsp</span>
```

He dejado todo en un *snippet* para que puedas probarlo aquí mismo en el navegador haciendo clic en el botón *"Ejecutar"*.

## Comparaciones entre cadenas y comparaciones entre números:

La explicación al comportamiento que ves es que estas realizando comparaciones entre cadenas de caracteres, que no se comportan como números, y de allí que tu rutina no funcione como esperas.

Para ayudarte a comprender la diferencia entre comparar cadenas de caracteres y comparar números, exploremos cada tipo de dato.

- [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) es una cadena de caracteres. Entendemos como *cadena* que es una estructura donde hay varios caracteres uno tras otro. Cada caracter es representado mediante un código numérico en memoria. Al comparar un caracter con otro, lo que realmente se compara es esa secuencia numérica. Para simplificar, me basaré en el código ASCII, sin olvidar que en javascript los caracteres están representados en memoria utilizando la codificación UTF16.

  En ASCII, el caracter '0' se representa por el número 48, el '1' por 49, '2' por 50 y así sucesivamente. El caracter '9' es el 57. La letra 'A' es el código 65, la 'B' es el 66, la 'C' el 67 y así sucesivamente. La 'Z' es el 90. La letra 'a' es código 97 y la 'z' es el 122.

  Así, el caracter '0' es *menor* al '1', dado que el código del '0' es menor que el código del '1'. El caracter 'A' es *menor* al caracter 'X', pero también es *menor* al caracter 'a'.

  El algoritmo de comparación de Strings va comparando caracter por caracter, para determinar si una cadena es igual, menor o mayor a otra. Dos cadenas son iguales si tienen exactamente los mismos caracteres, en el mismo orden y la misma longitud. Una cadena es mayora otra si el primer caracter donde difieren es mayor al de la otra. Así, la cadena '007' es *mayor* a la cadena '001', pero también es mayor a la cadena '001568'. Por la misma razón, '7' es *mayor* a '15', pues difieren en el primer caracter y '7' es *mayor* a '1'.

  Esto es útil, por ejemplo, para ordenar alfabéticamente, pues 'Castillo' es menor a 'Delgado', ya que la 'C' es menor a la 'D'. También 'Castillo' es menor a 'Cerezo', ya que 'a' es menor a 'e'.

  Pero, como puedes ver, la lógica de comparación, no es la *correcta* si dichas cadenas contienen números. Por *correcta* acá, me refiero a lo que un humano podría esperar al compararlas. La comparación si que es correcta, si tienes en cuenta la lógica programada en la computadora.
- [Números](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) Javascript, a diferencia de otros lenguajes, tiene un único tipo para representar números, independientemente de si se trata de números enteros o decimales. No vamos a entrar en detalle de como se representan estos valores en memoria, solo tener en cuenta que las comparaciones entre números funcionan como un humano podría esperar. Es decir, 1 es menor a 17 y a 1.001.

Finalmente, aceptar que javascript es *una locura*. Dado que no es un lenguaje *fuertemente tipado*, este permite realizar comparaciones entre variables de distinto tipo (cosa que no se puede en muchos otros lenguajes). Según el artículo [JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp), en su sección *Comparing Different Types*:

> Comparing data of different types may give unexpected results.
>
> When comparing a string with a number, JavaScript will convert the string to a number when doing the comparison. An empty string converts to 0. A non-numeric string converts to NaN which is always false

Mi traducción libre:

> Comparar datos de diferentes tipos puede dar lugar a resultados inesperados.
>
> Al comparar un string con un número, JavaScript convertirá el string a un número mientras realiza la comparación. Un string vacío se convierte a 0. Un string no numérico se convierte a NaN, que es siempre falso.

Según esto, podrías lograr tu cometido simplemente cambiando la comparación para hacerla contra los números 0 y 17, y no contra las cadenas '0' y '17'. Sin embargo, mi recomendación es que mantengas la consistencia entre tipos de datos siempre que sea posible, pues eso te evitará dolores de cabeza depurando comportamientos inesperados debido a estar realizando comparaciones entre distintos tipos de dato.

Comment: Muchas gracias creo que me ha servido mucho en verdad, ahora surge una duda si yo quiero almacenar el valor del resultado en un campo no en un span ???

Comment: seria con esta linea de codigo ??

Comment: `document.getElementById("Field3").value = r3`

Comment: Si, puede ser, siempre que el "campo" se llame "Field3".

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar si es mayor o menor a cierto valor antes debes transformarlo a un número (`parseInt`) y luego hacer la comparación.

```
} else if (parseInt(edad) <= 17) {
```