# Calcular edad en años, meses y días

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código, resultado de la incalculable ayuda de @Yusset y @bytespiller, permite calcular la edad en años, meses y días desde un botón de un explorador de archivos.

Y todo funciona bien excepto cuando el día de la fecha de nacimiento es mayor que el día de la fecha actual, ejemplo 28 y 22 respectivamente. En estos casos, el número de días informado es extremadamente grande, como si se estuviera en milisegundos.

Ejemplo:

Fecha nacimiento: **28**-01-2023
Fecha actual...........: **22**-08-2023

Edad...................: 6 meses, **2799900000000020** días
Edad correcta: 6 meses, **25** días.

.
**Parte del código encargado del cálculo**

```js
    //Calcular edad
    var dias = fecha2.getDate() - fecha1.getDate();
    var meses = fecha2.getMonth() - fecha1.getMonth();
    var anios = fecha2.getFullYear() - fecha1.getFullYear();

    if( dias < 0){
       var primerDiaProximoMes = new Date(fecha1.getFullYear(), fecha1.getMonth()+1, 1);
       var diff = primerDiaProximoMes - fecha1;
       var diasHastaFinMes = Math.floor(diff /  24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
       dias = diasHastaFinMes + fecha2.getDate() - 1; 

       meses--;
       }

       if (meses < 0){
         meses = 12 + meses;
         anios--;
    }
```

**Código completo**

```js
function OnClick(clickData)
{
    var dlg = clickData.func.Dlg;
    
    //Fecha nacimiento
    var fecha1String = dlg.getString("Fecha nacimiento (DD-MM-AAAA):");
    if (!fecha1String) {
        return;
    }

    //Covertir texto en fecha verdadera
    var fecha1Array = fecha1String.split("-"); //Se eliminan los guiones (-)
    var diaString = fecha1Array[0]; //1° bloque del array
    var mesString = fecha1Array[2]; //2° bloque del array
    var anioString = fecha1Array[2]; //3° bloque del array
    var fecha1 = new Date(anioString, parseInt(mesString) - 1, diaString); //Se obtine una fecha verdadera

    //Fecha actual
    var fecha2 = new Date();
    if (!fecha2) {
        return;
    }
        
    //Calcular tiempo
    var diff = fecha2 - fecha1; //En milisegundos
    var totalDias = Math.floor(diff / 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //En días

    //Personalizar fechas a mostrar (Formato DD-MM-AAAA, y días y meses con 2 dígitos (0 a la izquierda))
    var diaF1 = ("0" + fecha1.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mesF1 = ("0" + (fecha1.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    var anioF1 = fecha1.getFullYear();
    var fecha1Corta = diaF1 + "-" + mesF1 + "-" + anioF1

    var diaF2 = ("0" + fecha2.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mesF2 = ("0" + (fecha2.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    var anioF2 = fecha2.getFullYear();
    var fecha2Corta = diaF2 + "-" + mesF2 + "-" + anioF2

    //Mensaje de error si fecha1 > fecha2
    if(diff < 0){
    dlg.title = "Edad actual";
    dlg.message = "Error: La fecha de nacimiento tiene que ser menor que la fecha actual.\n\nFecha nacimiento: " + fecha1Corta + "\nFecha actual:        " + fecha2Corta;
    dlg.icon = "error";
    dlg.buttons = "Aceptar";
    dlg.Show();
    return;
    }

    //Calcular edad
    var dias = fecha2.getDate() - fecha1.getDate();
    var meses = fecha2.getMonth() - fecha1.getMonth();
    var anios = fecha2.getFullYear() - fecha1.getFullYear();

    if( dias < 0){
       var primerDiaProximoMes = new Date(fecha1.getFullYear(), fecha1.getMonth()+1, 1);
       var diff = primerDiaProximoMes - fecha1;
       var diasHastaFinMes = Math.floor(diff /  24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
       dias = diasHastaFinMes + fecha2.getDate() - 1; 

       meses--;
       }

       if (meses < 0){
         meses = 12 + meses;
         anios--;
    }

    //Ignorar valores 0 y establecer singular o plural
    var SEPARATOR = ", ";
    function que(value, singular, plural) {
        if (!value) {
            return "";
        }
        var suffix = (Math.abs(value) > 1) ? plural : singular;
        return value + " " + suffix + SEPARATOR;
    }

    var strAnios = que(anios, "año", "años");
    var strMeses = que(meses, "mes", "meses");
    var strDias = que(dias, "día", "días");

    var strTotal = (strAnios + strMeses + strDias).slice(0, -SEPARATOR.length);
    var edad = strTotal || "0 edad";

    // Mostrar resultado
    dlg.title = "Edad actual";
    dlg.message = "Fecha nacimiento: " + fecha1Corta + "\nFecha actual:        " + fecha2Corta + "\n\nEdad: " + edad;
    dlg.icon = "info";
    dlg.buttons = "Aceptar";
    dlg.Show();
  
}
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con más preciso? Ese `floor` lo único que está haciendo es quitar los decimales a tus cantidades. Normalmente no dices que tienes `18 años, 5 meses y 3.26 días`, no?

Comment: No son precisos en el sentido que si calculo la edad por otros medios, por ejemplo con la calculadora de Windows, los valores informados por este código no coinciden con los valores de Windows, Preguntaba si existe alguna función especializada en Fechas, que tenga en cuenta años bisiestos, días de cada mes, etc.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como obtener la edad de una persona en años, meses y dias en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376624/como-obtener-la-edad-de-una-persona-en-a%c3%b1os-meses-y-dias-en-javascript)

Comment: Hola de nuevo, cuando contestas algún mensaje, agrega **@nombreUsuario** para que este sea notificado (funciona si ha creado la pregunta/respuesta, o ha hecho un comentario en la misma), en el chat, abajo a la derecha tienes un enlace que dice algo como "logearse" tienes que volver a realizar el inicio de sesión para poder interactuar, no me has dicho si probaste con: **var fechaNacimiento = new Date( "2021-03-18" );**.

Comment: Hola @MarcePuente, gracias por las explicaciones, invítame al chat nuevamente para conversar por allá. Ese método si lo usé, pero no funcionó, lo actualicé con **var fechaNacimiento = new Date(2021, 03, 18);** y está funcionando bien.

Comment: Te dejo el link del [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147758/xavier-marce) así me contás bien.

Comment: Esta vez sí vi el link para iniciar la conversa, pero el problema ahora es que no tengo la reputación necesaria, ja ja, You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here.

Comment: Estamos en 2023! Considera utilizar `let` o `const` en lugar de `var`.

Comment: Hola @Mateo, hice las sustituciones que me recomendaste, pero no funciona, se genera error en plena línea 2, muchas gracias

Comment: @Xavier no veo los números, cuál sería? `var` crea las variables antes de que se llegue a la línea donde se declaran.

Comment: Los números solo los veo en la ventana de edición. La línea 2 es **var nacimiento = new Date(2017, 02 - 1, 01);**. Y no sé mucho de programación sobre eso de declaración y asignación de valores a variables, pero así como están las ```var``` funcionan

Answer (score 8):

El problema del método que utilizas es que a través de él puedes calcular segundos, minutos, horas, días y hasta semanas. Pero no puedes calcular ni años ni meses.

Y es porque los meses no es una unidad dependiente de los días, ya que la cantidad de días de cada mes es variable, mismo caso pasa con los años (por culpa de los bisiestos). No es equivalente al sistema metrico, que sabemos que en un kilometro hay siempre mil metros

#### ¿Pero como contamos el tiempo los humanos?

El método "humano" es bastante simple, del número nominal de un día hasta el próximo número del otro mes, es un mes. Por ejemplo, del `5 de enero` al `5 de febrero` es un mes, al `5 de marzo` son 2 meses (y así sucesivamente)

Y del `5 de enero` al `7 de febrero`, es un mes y dos días.

Entonces, si tenemos 2 fechas `desde` y `hasta`, podemos desglozar la diferencia de años, mes y días como:

```
 let dias  = hasta.getDate()     - desde.getDate(); 
 let meses = hasta.getMonth()    - desde.getMonth();
 let anios = hasta.getFullYear() - desde.getFullYear();
```

**¿El problema?**

Es que esté método no funciona cuando la fecha nominal del día `desde` es mayor a la de `hasta`, por ejemplo del `30 de enero` al `5 de marzo`, porque la diferencia (`5 - 30`) nos da negativo.

¿Como hacemos los humanos en estos caso?

Aquí contamos lo días hasta fin de mes y le sumamos los día de desde, entonces de 30 de enero al 31 de enero es un día y a eso le sumamos 5 (del 5 de feb), nos da que hay 6 días de diferencia. Y finalmente restamos 1 mes (de enero a febrero hay 1 mes, menos uno nos da cero meses)

Y volvemos a tener otro problema, que es saber que día es el fin de mes de ese mes correspondiente.

Lo que podemos hacer fácilmente es obtener el primer día del mes siguiente (todos los meses comienzan con el día uno)

```
let primer_dia_proximo_mes = new Date(desde.getFullYear(),desde.getMonth() +1 ,1);
```

Y luego calculamos la cantidad de días que quedan entre `desde` y `primer_dia_proximo_mes` (y restamos uno, porque realmente queremos el fin de mes anterior); y para calcular la cantidad de días entre ambas fecha usamos la ecuación de tu pregunta, porque tal como señalé al inicio SI sirve para calcular diferencia de días.

Nos queda entonces

```
if(dias<0){
    let primer_dia_proximo_mes = new Date(desde.getFullYear(),desde.getMonth() +1 ,1);
    let diff = primer_dia_proximo_mes - desde;
    let dias_hasta_fin_mes = Math.floor(diff /  (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
    dias = dias_hasta_fin_mes + hasta.getDate() - 1;
    meses--;
}
```

Ahora este mismo problema se reproduce con los meses, cuya diferencia tambien puede ser negativa si lo comparamos con años distintos (diciembre del 2022 a enero del 2023).

En este caso es mucho más simple, ya que los meses son constantes en un año, por lo que solo es necesario

```
if(meses<0){
    meses = 12 + meses;
    anios--;
  }
```

Juntando todo nos queda:

```js
function OnGetNewName(desde,hasta) {
 if(hasta - desde <=0) return "error";

 let dias = hasta.getDate() - desde.getDate(); 
 let meses = hasta.getMonth() - desde.getMonth();
 let anios = hasta.getFullYear() - desde.getFullYear();


 if(dias<0){
   let primer_dia_proximo_mes = new Date(desde.getFullYear(),desde.getMonth() +1 ,1);
    let diff = primer_dia_proximo_mes - desde;
    let dias_hasta_fin_mes = Math.floor(diff /  (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
    dias = dias_hasta_fin_mes + hasta.getDate() - 1;
    meses--;
  }
  
  if(meses<0){
    meses = 12 + meses;
    anios--;
  }
  
  return `(${anios}a ${meses}m ${dias}d)`;
}

console.log(OnGetNewName(new Date(2019, 1, 13),new Date(2023, 7, 12)));
console.log(OnGetNewName(new Date(2022,11,11),new Date(2023, 0, 1)));
console.log(OnGetNewName(new Date(2019, 1, 13),new Date(2023, 7, 12)));
console.log(OnGetNewName(new Date(2023, 6, 12),new Date(2023, 7, 11)));
console.log(OnGetNewName(new Date(2023, 6, 10),new Date(2023, 7, 11)));
```

*Nota: El algoritmo lo hice al vuelo, pueden existir casos de bordes que se me pasaron por alto. Favor revisar*

Update. Código completo

```js
function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData) {
    var item = getNewNameData.item;
    var metadata = item.metadata;
    
    if (!(metadata && metadata.image && metadata.image.datetaken)) return item.name;;
    
    var nacimiento = new Date(2019, 1, 13);
    var captura = new Date(metadata.image.datetaken);
   
    if (captura - nacimiento < 0) return item.name;;
    
    var diff = GetDiff(nacimiento, captura);
    
    return item.name_stem + " (" + diff + ")" + item.ext;
}



function GetDiff(desde,hasta) {


 var dias = hasta.getDate() - desde.getDate(); 
 var meses = hasta.getMonth() - desde.getMonth();
 var anios = hasta.getFullYear() - desde.getFullYear();


 if(dias<0){
   var primer_dia_proximo_mes = new Date(desde.getFullYear(),desde.getMonth() +1 ,1);
    var diff = primer_dia_proximo_mes - desde;
    var dias_hasta_fin_mes = Math.floor(diff /  (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
    dias = dias_hasta_fin_mes + hasta.getDate() - 1;
    meses--;
  }
  
  if(meses<0){
    meses = 12 + meses;
    anios--;
  }
  
  var respuesta = "";
  if(anios>0){
    respuesta = anios+"a";
  }
  
  if(meses>0){
    respuesta = respuesta + " " + meses + "m";
  }
  
  if(dias>0){
    respuesta = respuesta + " " + dias + "d";
  }
  
  return respuesta;
}

//SOLO PARA TEST
const ObjTest = {
  item : {
     metadata: {
        image: {
          datetaken : new Date(2023,7,12)
        }
     },
     name_stem : "stem",
     name: "name",
     ext: ".ext"
  }
};
console.log(OnGetNewName(ObjTest));
```

Comment: Hola @Yussef muchas, muchas gracias, que explicación, cuantos detalles, debes ser profesor, ja ja, voy a intentar aplicar tu código al mío, Dios quiera y funcione, no por ti que todo impecable, sino por mí que no sé mucho del tema, fuerte abrazo!

Comment: Hola @Yussef adapté tu código al mío, y algunas fechas se calculan bien, y otras no, debe ser cuestión de un pequeño detalle. Incorporé la adaptación a la pregunta, si un día pudieras analizar el código resultante te lo agradecería infinitamente.

Comment: @Xavier al final de mi respuesta he puesto un código que se acopla a lo tuyo (presiona sobre "Mostrar fragmento de código". Una aclaración `13-02-2019` al `12-08-2023` hay `4a 5m 27d` NO  `30d` como tu esperas, del 13 al 28 (porque es febrero) hay 15 días, luego tenemos todo marzo, abril, mayo junio, y julio (5 meses) más 12 días de agosto son `5m 27d`. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha sido de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: Hola @Yussef, de entrada muchas gracias por tanto esfuerzo. Por otra parte disculpa si informé que entre 13-02-2019 y 12-08-2023 existen 4a 5m 30d, pero ese fue el resultado de la calculadora de Windows. Respecto al nuevo código, remplacé todos los ```let``` por ```var``` porque sino, no funciona.

Comment: Al ejecutar el código se generó error en **if (!metadata?.image?.datetaken) return item.name;;**. Eliminé la línea para seguir comprobando el código y se generó otro error en **var texto = diff.filter(a=>a.valor>0).map(a=> a.valor + String(a.sufijo)).join(" ");**. Ahí paré porque no daría para continuar sin esa línea. Saludos y gracias una vez más!

Comment: @Xavier Revisé tus preguntas anteriores y vi que eres el usuario que preguntó sobre un script para un explorador de archivos de terceros. Esta pregunta sigue la misma línea???? Porque el error que te aparece es algo que puede pasar si usas un navegador antiguo

Comment: sí, las dos preguntas están relacionadas, el código que estoy queriendo aquí es para el mismo explorador de archivos de terceros (Directory Opus), pero no creo que el problema esté, pues él es bien moderno, bien potente, bien actualizado. El primer código que me pasaste no generó ningún error, muchas fechas las calculaba igual a Windows, solo alguna que, tal vez falta de una pequeña "calibrada", alguna condición simple

Comment: @Yussef, en explorador en cuestión, solo admite código de JScript o VBasic (el segundo puede que me equivoque.

Comment: @Xavier Me parece que es lo que dice Marce, es JScript (que es algo distinto a javascript). A esta altura de mi vida no recuerdo la diferencias de código entre ambos. He modificado el último código  a ver si con estos cambios te funciona.

Comment: @MarcePuente, los botones del explorador admiten funciones estándares, MS-DOS, JScript, y VBScript.

Comment: @Xavier, si, lo que pasa es que te están contestando con código en **javascript**, no se hasta donde son compatibles.

Comment: @Yussef yo pensaba que JavaScript y JScript eran la misma cosa, uno una abreviatura del otro, entonces estaba muy engañado, disculpen mi ignorancia. En los botones la opción que sale es JScript. Ok, voy a probar el código y después te cuento, desde ya mil veces gracias!

Comment: @Marce Puente esa va a ser la causa del problema, que verguenza

Comment: @Yussef acabé de adaptar el código y lo publiqué. Se ejecuta, no genera errores, pero no aplica el cálculo de la edad al nombre del archivo, tal vez no tenga nada a ver con tu código sino con el mío, que no supe adaptar bien el final del código, esa parte de pasar el resultado tuyo al nombre del archivo. Voy a revisarlo nuevamente. De todas formas, si tú también pudieras echarle un vistazo sería muy bueno.

Comment: @Holaaaa **@Yussef**, al fin, tu código, tus condiciones, tu razonamiento, todo ha sido perfecto. Que Dios te colme de bendiciones, **MIL VECES GRACIAS!!!**

Comment: @Marce Puente muchas gracias a ti también por el empeño de siempre, fuerte abrazo!

Comment: Hola @Yussef, no quería molestarte más, pero anoche estaba organizando unas fotos y descubrí que el código funciona perfectamente bien para la mayoría de las fechas, pero para algunas no. Por ejemplo: teniendo como fecha de nacimiento: 13-02-2019 (2019, 01, 13 en el código) para fotos con fecha de captura 01-01-2023, la fecha calculada es 3a 10m 16d, cuando, según la calculadora de Windows, es 3a 10m 19d. A qué se deberá ese comportamiento, que para unas fechas perfectamente bien y para otras no? Saludos!

Comment: Hola @dasota, como te decía al comienzo de mi respuesta, contar meses y años es algo complejo porque un mes es una unidad variable, por este motivo los embarazos se cuentan en semanas y no en meses. Desconozco (pero cuando tenga tiempo voy a averiguar) si existe una norma al respecto, yo cuento los días como el algoritmo que te he planteado y la calculadora de Windows lo hace de otra forma.

Comment: Lo primero es que yo cuento días completos del `1ro de enero` al `2 de enero` son 2 días, ya que desde el extremo inferior al superior pueden existir 48 horas, para otras personas es 1 día (esto es fácilmente solucionable restando siempre -1).  Después la diferencia viene en como completar el mes, veamos un ejemplo del `13 feb 2019` al `1 abr 2019`, yo digo del `13 feb` al `1 mar` son 16 días y del `1 mar` al `1 abr` son un mes, entonces da `1m 16d`

Comment: En cambio la calculadora de windows hace lo siguiente, dice del `13 feb` al `13 de mar` es 1 mes, y del `13 de mar` al `1 abr` son 19 días ¿Se entiende la diferencia? Yo completo los días del primer mes, en cambio windows completa los días del último mes. Esta diferencia de métodos traerá siempre una diferencia, la cual se acrecienta cuando febrero está involucrado

Comment: Entonces, a menos que existiera una norma oficial, tu deberás elegir un método que consideres mejor. Yo creo que el que te presento es mejor que el de la calculadora de windows. Considera que un mes tiene aproximadamente `30.43` días, del `13 feb 2019` al `1 abr 2019` son 47 días según la calculadora de windows, mi método da `1m 16` es decir `46.43` días, en cambio la calcula de windows dice que son `1m 19` es decir `49.43`, cual está más cerca??

Comment: Cierto @Yussef, el tema Tiempo es muy complejo, tanto en física, informática como en cualquier otro campo en el que se trate, por eso te agradezco tanto todo el tiempo y esfuerzo que te tomas en querer resolver este problema.

Comment: Respecto a la forma de considerar la diferencia de tiempo entre el ```1 de enero``` y el ```2 de enero```, yo creo que sea más razonable considerar que ha transcurrido 1 día, no solo porque así lo considera Windows, sino porque así se considera en otros campos, como por ejemplo en la Medicina, cuando se toma antibióticos o cuando se emite un certificado médico, los días se cuentan cada 24 horas cumplidas, por ejemplo, un evento con una duración de 28 horas es considerado apenas como 1 día, tendrán que transcurrir completamente otras 24 horas para considerar un 2° día.

Comment: Hablando del mes de febrero, sería bueno también crear una condición para tener en cuenta los años bisiestos, o no es necesario?!?

Comment: Realmente tu método calcula el tiempo absoluto de forma mucho más fiel que Windows, pero en la práctica, el de Windows tiene mayor aplicación. Que tal modificar el código para simular el estilo Windows y experimentar su comportamiento?!?

Comment: Pero ni sé si sea bueno adaptar tu código a otro método porque de la forma que está él calcula la mayoría de las fechas bien, idéntico a Windows, solo algunas que dan una variación de 2-3 días. Yo creo que tal vez todo lo que se necesite sea implementar alguna condición más para posibles fechas como la del 01-01-2023.

Comment: Hola @Yussef, no te olvides de mí, cuando puedas dame una mano con el código, fuerte abrazo!

Answer (score 3):

Una posible aproximación al problema sería restar una fecha a la otra (como ya haces) y proceder de la siguiente forma:

Primero calcula los días totales entre  las dos fechas. Después, los años (enteros, con el floor como haces) de días. Si restas a los dias totales  el número de años que te resultan * 365 ya tienes la diferencia en años y días. Acuérdate, eso sí, de restarle al resto de días (valga la redundancia) un día por cada año bisiesto que te cayera en el intervalo de años completos (para ser exactos en el cálculo).

Con ese resto de días puedes hacer lo mismo para los meses, pero teniendo en cuenta que comienzas en el mes de la primera fecha (ya que hemos eliminado años completos del resto).

Aquí puedes proceder tomando los días reales de cada mes (teniendo en cuenta bisiestos) o usando un número de días medio por mes (tipo 30).

No obstante, en pos de la simplicidad y la exactitud, y suponiendo (claro) que el planteamiento del problema te lo permita, yo me quedaría con la expresión en años y días de la diferencia.

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Librería Days.js

También se puede usar la librería days.js que hace uso de un calendario y puede ofrecerte los resultados que esperas:

https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference

Comment: Gracias @Hnry23 por tu comentario, pero de esta forma el resultado tampoco sería completamente fiel. Yo pensé que existiera alguna función como existe en Excel, por ejemplo: (SIFECHA(Fecha1;Fecha2;"md") que extrae los días libres entre dos fechas

Comment: También puedes hacer uso de la librería Days.js que usa un calendario. He editado la respuesta para incluirte el enlace abajo.

Comment: Que bien, eso luce muy interesante, gracias una vez más, voy a leer el artículo!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero te invito a leer [answer]. Una buena respuesta siempre mostrará un [mre], sobre todo cuando se trata de JS, ya que el sitio dispone de un *snippet* que puedes usar para ejecutar tu ejemplo. Por otro lado, siempre es buena idea buscar en el sitio por si esta pregunta ya ha sido respondida en algún otro momento, ya que las preguntas duplicadas suelen cerrarse, haciendo que tu respuesta pierda relevancia en el sitio.

Comment: Gracias @Mauricio Contreras por tus recomendaciones, pero antes de pedir ayuda aquí, indagué por todas partes, adapté códigos y más códigos, pero para quien no es un profesional en el área, cualquier cosa resulta difícil

Comment: También podrías probar la biblioteca date-fns

Comment: Muchas gracias @Laura por tu recomendación, pero no sabría hacer eso